What happens if a proton conductor electrode is used for electrolysis of tris(cyclopentadienyl)lanthanum?
To attempt a deposition of $\ce{La}$ thin films inside a conductive organogel electrode, let's consider the following setup:
There are two liquids in two cells, separated by a proton conductive wall: the first one is an aqueous acid solution, the second one is an organic solvent and tris(cyclopentadienyl)lanthanum, $\ce{LaCp3}$ solute, inside and around the gel electrode.
The gel electrode does not touch the proton conductive wall, but both liquids do.
The positive electrode is submerged into the aqueous cell.
Questions

Is the organic solution going to conduct electricity by any species at all, given that it must be chosen unreactive towards $\ce{La^3+}$ solid compound formation?
If protons are transported from the aqueous side, through the proton conductive wall, into the organic solution, are they going to cause $\ce{LaCp3}$ to lose cyclopentadiene?
Does $\ce{La}$ metal deposit?
Is there a strong tendency for depositing the metal onto the outer surface of the piece of organogel or can the thin film form uniformly into the pores of the gel for a suitable $\ce{LaCp3}$ concentration choice and voltage choice?
Is it reasonable to assume that the setup works near or below room temperature?

